# Is there a way to iterate through the first and second row of an array in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I'm quite new to Angular2, basically I have a multi dimensional array like so

[[Object1, Object2, Object3], [Object2, object4], [Object6]]

I want to iterate through the first row of the array like so:

```
 <td class="tableInvisible" *ngFor="let item of currentCourse.toets[0];">{{item}}</td>
```

But this gives me an `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./CursussenComponent class CursussenComponent - inline template:219:53 caused by: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

The 0 index is clearly there when I console.log it, so for some reason it's not accepting me specifying the index.

Comment: Could you please share the exact code, how the array looks like?

Comment: This is the array that I'm trying to iterate through, I must note that the array does get generated and processed with a REST call before the whole thing loads if that has anything to do with my problem. http://prntscr.com/finkon, code of how the array gets created: https://pastebin.com/X5p0QEig @JEETADHIKARI